# Runtime error in replace function?

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

I wrote a program to find and replace a line in a file. The program is as such:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    fstream f,g; string s,s2,s3;
    f.open("sasuke.txt",ios::in);
    g.open("konoha.txt",ios::out);
    cout<<"Enter line to be replaced: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,s2);
    cout<<"To be replaced with? "<<endl;
    getline(cin,s3);
    while(getline(f,s)){
        s.replace(s.find(s2),s2.size(),s3);
        g<<s<<endl;
    }
    g.close();
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The error I'm given is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 105)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone please explain me why this error is given and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to check whether the string was found first with `s.find(s2)` *before* running `replace`.

Comment: What happens if the line is not found?

Comment: When an exception is thrown that you never catch, terminate() is called automatically.

Comment: I would've added an if statement for that, but first I tried it by inputting a line that was in the file. It still showed this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens. Let's say the line you want to replace is "src", which is to be replaced with "dst". Now, your program goes through the input text file line-by-line, and replaces whenever it finds "src" with "dst". However, at some point of time, it meets with a line that doesn't contain any text "src". Then, find returns some invalid number and the program terminates complaining that the position you gave for replacement is invalid.

So let's say your sasuke.txt is as follows:

```
this is src
this line has src
this line too has src
but not this line
```

Now, your code will run till the last line where it will terminate. To prove this, I added a little cout in the while loop. See the output:

```
Enter line to be replaced: 
src
To be replaced with? 
dst
in the while loop
this is src
in the while loop
this line has src
in the while loop
this line too has src
in the while loop
but not this line
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is     18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 17)
```

Solution is that you need to do the find() operation first, see if the position returned is valid and only then exectue replace. For me this worked:

```
while(getline(f,s)){
    size_t pos = s.find(s2);
    if(pos < s.length())
        s.replace(pos,s2.size(),s3);
    g<<s<<endl;
}
```